# How to bind a kernel patches to different recipes

Tags: yocto, recipe

I have two similar boards. I want to write a recipe for each of them. But they will have different kernel patches.How to do it better? Or Should I add new machines to the build?

---

I added my-machine to mylayer/local.conf

```
MACHINEOVERRIDES = "imx8qmmek:my-machine"
```

I created mylayer/recipex-kernel/linux/linux-imx_%.bbappend with my-patch:

```
SRC_URI_imx8qmmek += " file://0001-add-modified-dts.patch "
SRC_URI_imx8qmmek += " file://0002-EP4668-wifi-bt-modified-dts.patch "
SRC_URI_imx8qmmek += " file://0003-EP4822-enable-USB3-hub.patch "
SRC_URI_my-machine += " file://0004-EP4827-comment-usdhc3.tcu.patch "
SRC_URI_imx8qmmek += " file://EP4133_added_BRCM-PCIE.cfg"


do_configure_append_imx8qmmek() {

    bbnote "adding BRCM-PCIE configuration ${PN}"
        cat ../*.cfg >> ${B}/.config

}
```

And I run command:

```
MACHINE="my-machine" bitbake -c clean linux-imx
```

But a terminal outputed the error:
WARNING: Layer meta-mylayer should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_mylayer in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
WARNING: Layer meta-mylayer should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_meta-mylayer in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
WARNING: You have included the meta-gnome layer, but 'x11' has not been enabled in your DISTRO_FEATURES. Some bbappend files may not take effect. See the meta-gnome README for details on enabling meta-gnome support.
WARNING: Host distribution "ubuntu-18.04" has not been validated with this version of the build system; you may possibly experience unexpected failures. It is recommended that you use a tested distribution.
ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

```
MACHINE=my-machine is invalid. Please set a valid MACHINE in your local.conf, environment or other configuration file.
```

Comment: You need to create a new machine configuration file. It's its own file, in `meta-mylayer/conf/machine/`. In this file, you'll probably require the one for imx8qmmek and then before the require, add `MACHINEOVERRIDES =. "imx8qmmek:"` or something close to that.
`SRC_URI_<machine>` even with a += will actually override whatever was in `SRC_URI` before. You need to use `SRC_URI_append_<machine>` instead, don;t forget the leading space.
Then, fix the warnings you have, they are pretty explicit already. But the error comes from the absence of a machine configuration file named my-machine.conf.

Comment: Qschulz, thank you for the usefull advice. I fixed the problem. I created two bbappend files in recipes-kernel/linux : linux-imx_%.machine1.bbappend, linux-imx_%.machine2.bbappend, added machine1.conf, machine2.conf in machine/conf. And I described all parameters with suffix-machine accordingly (ex: VAR_machine1 in linux-imx_%.machine1.bbappend, VAR_machine2 in linux-imx_%.machine2.bbappend). But many parameters are common for both machine. How can I mark the parameters for using in both machines? And can I use parameter COMPATIBLE_MACHINE? How can I use two defconfig for kernel of machines?

Comment: I'm very surprised your bbappend work actually. I've never seen that done this way before and I doubt it's actually applying the bbappend for a machine only (there is no condition for applying a bbappend except the version matching in the filename).
If you add a common name to `MACHINEOVERRIDES` for both machines, then you'll be able to use that one instead of the machine name. `COMPATIBLE_MACHINE` works on the recipe level, and since bbappends are unconditionally applied, I don't think it'll do what you expect.

Comment: defconfig handling is specific to each linux kernel recipe. One possibility is to declare in your machine that it is using a defconfig named `my-machine_defconfig` that is already in the kernel git repo. Then you just need two different defconfigs in the git repo.
Second way is to have defconfig in `SRC_URI` and add two in different paths. One in the path `/path/to/recipe/linux-imx/machine1/defconfig` and the other in `/path/to/recipe/linux-imx/machine2/defconfig`. Yocto will pick the right one.
There are other ways too, but those are I think the most common and cleanest ways to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar != identical. If they are indeed slightly different, then two machines is the way to go. If they are sufficiently similar (to be determined by yourself :) ), different distros is also an option. All depends on how different the machines are and how different the final images should be (might need two machines or two distros or both).

If you have two similar machines but need two machine configuration files, put most of the common code into an .inc required by both machines. Don't forget to put a `MACHINEOVERRIDES` somewhere in that inc file with a name that will make sense for both machines (e.g., if you have rpi3-lcd and rpi3-iot, have an rpi3-common.inc with `rpi3-common` added to `MACHINEOVERRIDES`). This will make it possible to use `VAR_rpi3-common` in recipes that have patches or machine specific stuff in your recipes to apply to both without needing `VAR_rpi3-lcd` AND `VAR_rpi3-iot`.

Comment: Thank you. How to rebuild kernel with different patches?
Now, I rebuild with command: bitbake linux-imx

Comment: `MACHINE=rpi3-lcd bitbake linux-imx` if you've made your patches dependent on the `rpi3-lcd` machine for example. If it's a different distro, `DISTRO=my-distro bitbake linux-imx`, provided you've made the patches distro specific. Another option is to change the `MACHINE` or `DISTRO` in `conf/local.conf` directly. Up to you.

Comment: But my current build has a MACHINE=imx8qmmek. If I change a machine on for example my-machine will it not break down mu build?

Comment: Break down? What will happen is that machine specific packages will be rebuilt so it might take a bit longer than usual (for the first build, afterwards it's fine). If there are packages that can be built only for `imx8qmmek` or some `VAR_imx8qmmek` and your board is actually a direct variant of this machine, making use of `MACHINEOVERRIDES` with an added `imx8qmmek` seems fine to me.